# Yeoman sub generators for MEAN application?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, mean-stack, yeoman-generator, mean.io

I've been playing with Mean.IO (http://mean.io/), and wondered if there was a Yeoman generator (sub-generator?) that I could use to auto-generate code for an "entity" across the entire stack.  For example, in the mean.io project there is an "Article" example that contains 7 components related to "Articles" (Model, Controller, Node Routes, Angular Routes/Service/Controller/Views).  Is there a generator that will create this "component stack" for a custom entity?

eg, something like:

yo meangenerator:entity 'MyEntity'

would then create 7 different files that tie 'MyEntity' into an existing MEAN application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couldn't really find anything that worked how i wanted, so I wrote my own.  My first Yeoman generator, as well as first real interaction with github and https://npmjs.org/.  Fun!

GitHub:
https://github.com/MartyIce/generator-meancrud

NPM:
https://npmjs.org/package/generator-meancrud

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think they have something similar, like:

$ mean package ThingIWantToModel

Don't know if they created this feature after you asked.

I wonder if we can generate singular controllers, models, and anything else inside this package.

Answer (score 0):

Mean.js (another project that is similar to mean.io) has a great module generator, as does the angular-generator-fullstack project.

I think mean.js is the best, though, as it comes out-of-box with everything you need to actually get started building your application, including user logins, registration, reset password, change password, and a user management interface. Basically, batteries are included and you are ready to get building!